# Html not showing 2 column

Tags: css, html

**Problem**

I am expecting to showing two columns. But all the four fields are coming in 1 column.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <main class="py-4">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header">Update Profile</div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <form method="POST" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="profileForm">
                  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="First_Name" class="control-label">First Name</label>

                      <input class="form-control" name="First_Name" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="Last_Name" class="control-label">Last Name</label>
                      <input class="form-control" name="Last_Name" type="text">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group ">
                      <label for="City" class="control-label">City</label>
                      <input class="form-control" name="City" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group ">
                      <label for="State" class="control-label">State</label>
                      <input class="form-control" name="State" type="text">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also, your labels don't match your inputs. You should look into that too.

Comment: add `.row` class to your form or its container

Comment: @Stavm That works only on the form, not on its container. The row must be the direct parent of the col.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work.

Adding a row div just before the two form fields you are expecting in the same column.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <main class="py-4">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-10">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header">Update Profile</div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <form method="POST" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="profileForm">
                  <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="FirstName" class="control-label">First Name</label>
                      <input class="form-control" name="First_Name" type="text">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="LastName" class="control-label">Last Name</label>
                      <input class="form-control" name="Last_Name" type="text">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                    <div class="form-group ">
                      <label for="City" class="control-label">City</label>
                      <input class="form-control" name="City" type="text">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                    <div class="form-group ">
                      <label for="State" class="control-label">State</label>
                      <input class="form-control" name="State" type="text">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a div with class "row", this will take all the width avaible

```
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">...</div>
       <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">...</div>
   </div>
```